# Send variable using jquery (ajax) and phonegap

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to make a mobile application. One page “allpeople.html” has a set of links which are generated via a loop from based on Information from XML file.

Basically what I want is when the user clicks the link the variable is sent to a jquery  (ajax) script on the “showResult.html” page which will have a script (again jquery and Ajax)

So it is linke this

```
var value1=John;
var value2=Male;
```

//post variables to the function “theCustomFunction” on resultspage.html

```
$.post('resultspage.html', function(theCustomFunction:”value1”,”value2”) {
});
```

//on the  showResult.html page

```
<script>
   function : theCustomFunction( value1,value2) {
      var name= value1;
      var sex= value2;
      etc ....
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think jquery is the best. you can send data this way too:

```
$.post('resultspage.html', {name:'John',sex:'male'});
```

you can use variables too:

```
var value1='John';
var value2='Male';
$.post('resultspage.html', {name:value1,sex:value2});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but how is the function set in the resultspage.html to receive these vars (As you are not passing the vars to any particular function in the response above. Thanks fior your answer.